# Executing CUDA code In Matlab

Tags: matlab, cuda

I wanted to ask if anyone have run some C code containing CUDA code on Matlab?

I have read the documentation on Mathworks website but I still cant quite wrap my head around it. I do understand that it is two main type of ways you could do this either executing a CUDA kernel by constructing a object with the function `parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel` or by constructing a **mex file out of a .cu file**. There are some things though I do not understand when using these two methods.

- Using the mex approach should I use another IDE like Visual Studio to compile a .cu file first before compiling the mex file in Matlab? If so how can I compile the .cu file without a main() function in the .cu file, I always get errors when I try to compile it that way in VS, or is it okay to have a main function in the .cu  file and pass the pointers to the GPU arrays to the main function?
- For the CUDA kernel approach, should compile the kernel in VS, and in that case how?

Comment: When using the `mexcuda`command, you don't need another IDE. The .cu file is compiled by Matlab. But under Windows, Matlab will need the Visual cpp compiler. Depending on the Matlab version and CUDA toolkit version, it needs to be a specific version of the visual compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Both things can work.

If you want to have flexibility, my suggestion is to write your .cu files with .c (or .cpp) files*. Once you have some basic thing working, you should be able to write [a mex wrapper around it](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html) in order to grab MATLAB variables and convert them co C/C++ so you can pass them to and from CUDA. This requires you to have a compiler that is both compatible with your versions of MATLAB, CUDA and OS. An example is Visual Studio 2013 in widows and most versions of MATLAB and CUDA, but please check. Generally this is done by linking nvcc to the mex compiler after setup with some xml files (see [example here from my toolbox](https://github.com/CERN/TIGRE/blob/master/MATLAB/mex_CUDA_win64_MVS2013.xml)). This approach gives you full flexibility, not only for working with CUDA, but also with working with the anything that you may want to use together with your kernels e.g. tensorflow, eigen, SQL, ... Its full flexibility.

If instead you just want a few operations accelerated with simple methods, use the Parallel computing toolbox with `gpuarray`s for standard MATLAB operations or with [`parallel.gpu.CUDAKernel`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html) for your own kernels. To use this second one you need to compile a ptx file, [which seems pretty straightforward](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html#bsic4zj). A priori this gives you less flexibility, as it will run just a kernel, but often complex GPU programs may need several kernels and data handling techniques, as well as communication between kernels etc. However I have personally haven't tried it and perhaps you can achieve full flexibility. Let me know and I will edit the answer.

In short, you choice depends on your application/needs.

*You might not need .c or .cpp files with modern versions of MATLAB and `mexcuda`.

Comment: Why adding .c or .cpp files instead of just having a .cu file and compile it with `mexcuda`?

Comment: @AmosEgel I must admit I need to renew my knowledge with latest version of this, as I have basically used 2014b where this was the only way (`mexcuda` is 2016b I believe). However, if you do only a .cu file, do you add the `void mexFunction(int  nlhs , mxArray *plhs[],
        int nrhs, mxArray const *prhs[])` as function name? Do you not need to convert from MATLAB types to CUDA types?

Comment: @AmosEgel The obvious added value of having a c/cpp file is also backwards compatibility, ofc.

Comment: Yes, when using `mexcuda` you typically have two functions in the .cu file: The kernel as a `__global__` and the `mexFunction` as a `void`. In the latter, the Matlab input is converted to CUDA types and the cuda kernel is called.

Comment: @AmosEgel I see I see. On personal preference, I still like having a separate .c file, as this allows me to separate between input handling and computational operations easily and makes the software modular. I added a comment to reflect the posibility of not needing .c files.

Comment: In that respect, using only a .cu file (and no .cpp) has the disadvantage that the way how the .cu file is written is specific for Matlab. When using the same kernel from another language like Python you would remove the `mexFunction`. But the advantage is that you need to manage less files and learn less.

Comment: @AmosEgel indeed! Ultimately, it ends up being a philosophical choice, not  a programming one ;)